# In what way can this off-topic question be salvaged by editing?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

I flagged [Use Windows as secondary monitor on chrome os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221939/use-windows-as-secondary-monitor-on-chrome-os) as Very Low Quality.

Here's the question text:

> Is it possible to work on chrome os as the main monitor and use a windows PC as a secondary monitor to chrome? I have searched on the internet but could not find anything.

My flag was marked *Disputed*.

> very low quality – Robert Columbia yesterday   disputed

I'm struggling to understand how this question does not meet the definition of Very Low Quality:

> "This question has severe formatting or content problems."

It's blatantly off-topic, and in such a way that a simple edit, *even by the OP*, will not fix it. It's not like off-topic "debug my code" questions that can be made on-topic by editing in an MCVE.

> "This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing...."

There doesn't seem to be much, if any, scope for bringing this question to an on-topic state. Even if there was a marginal possibility, the likelihood of someone doing so for a question like this is very low.

> "...and might need to be removed."

It's clogging up our site, sending a silent message to others that we tolerate such questions in our community. This is clearly one that "might" need to be removed, and one that in fact *should* be removed if there is no path to redemption for it.

I *did* Vote to Close and downvote too, but the question is still sitting there with one close vote and -1.

What am I not understanding about question quality here? How can this question be salvaged through editing or otherwise redeemed?

Answer (score 7):

The question features coherent writing. You are able to tell what the question is about. That alone disqualifies it from VLQ. A VLQ question is so poorly written or formatted as to be incomprehensible (in other words, a question your first instinct would be to vote unclear rather than off-topic).

A question that's blatantly off-topic doesn't need to go away any quicker than any other off-topic question, and doesn't need anything beyond the usual close-delete/Roomba workflow. Sure, such a question can't be salvaged by editing, but that's meant to be a description of how incoherent the content is, not how far off-topic the otherwise coherent content is.